# rsync doesn't always sync changes made for web server

Tags: rsync

I use rsync to update my website, but lately it has been giving me some issues.  I use the command

`rsync -uvrP --delete-after COMPUTER/ WEB-SERVER/`

but it doesn't always update after I've changed a file.  It used to do it every time, and for awhile it hiccuped a few times, but now I have to ssh into the server, delete everything, and THEN rsync will sync it.  Obviously, this isn't the most efficient method, and I'm wondering what might be up.

Or sometimes if I made a lot of changes, the update/sync will go through, but it's becoming quite frustrating, and wondering what might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the "*some issues*" actually are, the only problem I can see is that your command is wrong. You're telling the system not to update files if they are newer on the target, but you're not sending file timestamps. Furthermore you are allowing partial updates, so any interruption will potentially leave you with a new file that's incomplete but newer than the original.

```
rsync -avuP COMPUTER/ WEB-SERVER/
```

Unless you can have files on `WEB-SERVER` that are updated independently of `COMPUTER` then you should remove `-u`